# Voronoi decomposition implementation in four dimensions?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, discrete-geometry

I'm a software engineer and have been asked to research a Voronoi implementation in four dimensions. I'm not asking for "teh codez" but *am* interested in approachable tutorials on Voronoi decomposition and/or implementations in any dimension. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard survey is [Aurenhammer and Klein](http://www.pi6.fernuni-hagen.de/publ/tr198.pdf).  Have you looked at that?

[This would be a comment, but I don't have enough rep on this site yet]

Answer (score 4):

Even though you didn't ask for 'teh codez' :), [qvoronoi](http://www.qhull.org/html/qvoronoi.htm) is a pretty good implementation of Voronoi diagrams for low dimensions (i.e 4). It actually computes the Delaunay triangulation, which in turn is constructed by a convex hull algorithm (qhull) one dimension higher.

The convex hull algorithm itself [is a combination of](http://www.qhull.org/html/index.htm#algorithm) "the 2-d Quickhull algorithm with the n-d beneath-beyond algorithm [c.f., Preparata & Shamos '85]"